# How to import a .d.ts file and how to use class it declared?

Tags: javascript, import, protocol-buffers

I want to import area.js (module testt) into MyModule.ts.
The area.js has a area.d.ts file.

`area.d.ts`:

```
import * as $protobuf from "../node_modules/protobufjs/minimal";

/** Properties of a ProtoArea. */
export interface IProtoArea
{
}

/** Represents a ProtoArea. */
export class ProtoArea
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

`MyModule.ts`:

```
import ProtoArea = require("../libs/area");
module testt{
    export function MyModuleFunc():void
    {
        console.log("in MyModuleFunc function");

        // let msg = ProtoArea.create();
        // let buffer = ProtoArea.encode(msg).finish();
        // let decode = ProtoArea.decode(buffer);
        // console.log(`buffer = ${Array.prototype.toString.call(buffer)}`);

    }

    export class MyClass
    {
        public callClassFunc():void
        {
            console.log("MyClass->callClassFunc()");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `LayaSample.ts`:

```
import te = testt.MyModuleFunc;
class GameMain{
    constructor()
    {
        Laya.init(600,400, 0x000000);

        console.log("start");
        te();

        let cls = new testt.MyClass();
        cls.callClassFunc();
    }
}
new GameMain();
```

If I add this code in MyModule.ts, it fails on compilation:

Cannot find name 'testt'.
Cannot find namespace 'testt'.

```
import ProtoArea = require("../libs/bundle");
```

If Commenting it, compiled without error.
So What's wrong with it?
How can I import it? And How to use class ProtoArea declared in area.d.ts?
I am a fresher of JS and TS. I tried several days. And I found I can import a module like this:

```
import te = testt.MyModuleFunc;
```

but no idea to .d.ts..
I tried like these:

```
import pa = require("../libs/area.d.ts");
import {pa} from "../libs/area";
import ProtoArea as pa from "../libs/area";
import Pa = require("ProtoArea");
require("ProtoArea");
require("../libs/area");
```

etc.
None of them works.
Thanks for your help.